# Cannot trigger an onchange event added dynamically with jQuery between iframes

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, triggers, bind

I have an iframe and need to trigger an onchange event from his parent (or from another iframe). Actually I only can trigger events if I have specified them "inline" but not if I have used the jQuery .bind() function.

If the event if trigger from the iframe works for both cases.

The case is the following: 
I have an input like this.

```
<input type="hidden" id="changed" value="" onchange="alert('inline onchange');" >
```

and bind dynamically an onchange event

```
$("#changed").bind("change",function(){alert("bind onchange");});
```

If i trigger the onchange event from the iframe, the two methods are executed:

```
$("#changed").trigger("change");
```

But if I trigger the event from the parent, only the first method is executed:

```
$('#childIframe', window.parent.document).contents().find("#changed").trigger("change");
```

You can see the example working in http://jsbin.com/lobow